# Angular component loses its metadata during transpiling

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, angular2-decorators

YET ANOTHER: `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'UserDialogComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`

### Current behavior

summary: Including an external library that uses `reflect-metadata` causes an error like this one: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15890

### Expected behavior

Adding an external library that uses the same polyfill doesn't have to cause errors.

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

Error description: There are two components:

AppComponent and UserDialogComponent

As I see UserDialogComponent behave as if was not decorated with `@Component` but that's not true. The problem relies on reflect metadata polyfills I think. If I remove decorators added by `kaop-ts` library everything goes well. But it worked before adding UserDialogComponent :\

repo with error: https://github.com/k1r0s/angular2-aop-showcase/
branch: iss-angular-reflection
steps to reproduce: clone repo, git checkout origin/iss-angular-reflection, npm install, ng serve

aditional info (images with error trace):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxxQH.jpg

Attached images: With Chrome dev tools if you set "pause on exception", then you go up on callstack two times and then you evaluate: `meta.declarations[1]` You should get UserDialogComponent constructor reference, and then you can execute: `Reflect.getMetadata("annotations", meta.declarations[1])` **in order to retrieve component metadata** but it returns undefined whereas `Reflect.getMetadata("annotations", meta.declarations[0])` will successfuly return AppComponent's medatada ... this is kinda bizarre..

### What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

By removing third party decorators Angular components mantain their metadata

### Environment

```
Angular version: 4.0.0
package.json (project was generated with angular-cli)
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "kaop-ts": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },

Browser:
- [x] Chromium (desktop) version `Version 59.0.3071.109 (Developer Build)` 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v6.11.2
- Platform: Linux
```

Thanks!

Comment: That seems to be a bug report, why have you posted it here? Do you have a *question?*

Comment: `steps to reproduce: clone repo, npm install, ng serve` It works without any errors

Comment: @yurzui which repo branch have you checked?, did you browse the repo?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I opened an issue on angular's repo. But I though someone can answer this here too

Comment: I've checked https://github.com/k1r0s/angular2-aop-showcase/tree/iss-angular-reflection

Comment: @yurzui So maybe is a problem with my dependencies or angular-cli version though.. :\

Comment: @yurzui did you ` $ git checkout origin/iss-angular-reflection`

Comment: My bad :) I thought there are no other branches there

Comment: gonna update the issue :|

Comment: What do you expect if you're overriding current global Reflect object?

Comment: Add `import { afterMethod } from "kaop-ts";
console.log(afterMethod);` to top of `main.ts` file and then it should work
`

Comment: @yurzui 

1: why im overriding global reflect object?
2: why declaring kaop-ts at main.ts fix angular reflection?
3: now im facing another error which angular overrides kaop-ts behavior by calling wrong this on decorator..

Comment: Open `node_modules/kaop-ts/dist/kaop-ts.es5.js` for example 229 line `Reflect.defineMetadata = defineMetadata;` Reflect uses private map variable to store defined metadata. You defined data in one map, but try to get from other map

Comment: @yurzui u're a boss

Comment: I'll open a new question titled: "What should I do in order to use reflect metadata from other libraries with angular projects"

Answer (score 0):

as @yurzui pointed, reflect-metadata package overrides global references so it conflicts with, for example core-js.

The solition, in my case, was replace `reflect-metadata` package for `core-js` and then, include in my build an scoped polyfill reflect from core-js.

The correct explanation about why with one component wasn't any problem is because decorators are evaluated when class is declared, so when angular decorators are evaluated, it is painless to evaluate third party decorators, as javascript has already stored metadata within memory and can be accessed. Problem was with another component because after first component was declared, typescript evaluates following method decorators from third party libraries which use `reflect-metadata` by reasigning current global `Reflect` object... (polluting global namespace.. ) and then, angular try to load second component but @component can no longer store metadata where it needs to be placed, so angular complains about 2nd component has no `@component` declaration which is annoying and bizarre in first hand.